# Setting an option to a string containing control characters

Tags: options, control-character

I'm trying to configure Vim to be able to properly determine the background color when run inside GNU Screen.  I know I need to set the option `t_RB` to the string `\eP\e]11;?\x03\e\\` (where `\e` is the Escape character) when `$TERM` starts with `screen`, but I can't figure out how to use control characters in the `set` command.

First attempt:

```
if stridx(environ()['TERM'], 'screen') == 0
    set t_RB=<ESC>P<ESC>]11;?<C-G><ESC>\\
endif
```

This just set `t_RB` to the literal string `<ESC>P<ESC>]11;?<C-G><ESC>\`, which gets output as soon as I start up Vim.  I also tried enclosing the string in single quotes, but that didn't help.

Second attempt:

```
if stridx(environ()['TERM'], 'screen') == 0
    set t_RB="\eP\e]11;?\x07\e\\"
endif
```

This seemed to just set `t_RB` to the empty string.  I tried again without the quotes and with single quotes; these just resulted in `t_RB` being set to the string as written, with literal `\e` instead of an Escape character.

How do I `:set` an option to a string containing control characters?

Comment: To precisely answer your question would be good to know what is exactly the value you like to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
if stridx(environ()['TERM'], 'screen') == 0
    let &t_RB="\<ESC>P\<ESC>]11;?\<C-G>\<ESC>\\"
endif
```

Comment: I had to strip off two of the backslashes at the end to get what I wanted, but otherwise this worked.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have adapted the solution. Let me know if the adapted solution is now correct in case other would be interested :-)

Comment: Yes, it's now correct.